# How can I add new attributes to a pandas.DataFrame derived class?

Tags: python, pandas, init, derived-class, class-attributes

I want to create a class derived from `pandas.DataFrame` with a slightly different `__init__()`. I'll store some additional data in new attributes and finally call `DataFrame.__init__()`.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class DataFrameDerived(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.derived = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

DataFrameDerived({'a':[1,2,3]})
```

This code gives the following error when creating the new attribute (`self.derived = True`):

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *possible*, but the implementation isn't very open to extension. Indeed, the [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) suggest using alternatives. The implementation of `pd.DataFrame` is complex, involving multiple inheritance with various mixins, and also, it uses the various attribute setting/getting hooks, like `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, to among other things, provide syntactic sugar like using `df.some_column` and `df.some_colum = whatever` to work without using the `df['some_column']` syntax.  If you look at the stack trace, you can see that *something* is going on with `__setattr__`:

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 8
      5         self.derived = True
      6         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
----> 8 DataFrameDerived({'a':[1,2,3]})

Cell In[1], line 5, in DataFrameDerived.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      4 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
----> 5     self.derived = True
      6     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:6014, in NDFrame.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   6012 else:
   6013     try:
-> 6014         existing = getattr(self, name)
   6015         if isinstance(existing, Index):
   6016             object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5986, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5976 """
   5977 After regular attribute access, try looking up the name
   5978 This allows simpler access to columns for interactive use.
   5979 """
   5980 # Note: obj.x will always call obj.__getattribute__('x') prior to
   5981 # calling obj.__getattr__('x').
   5982 if (
   5983     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5984     and name not in self._metadata
   5985     and name not in self._accessors
-> 5986     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5987 ):
   5988     return self[name]
   5989 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Knowing this, one might *blindly* just use `object.__setattr__` instead, to bypass this:

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame
   ...:
   ...: class DataFrameDerived(DataFrame):
   ...:     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         object.__setattr__(self, 'derived', True)
   ...:         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   ...:
   ...: DataFrameDerived({'a':[1,2,3]})
Out[1]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

But again, without really understanding the implementation, you are just crossing your fingers and hoping "it works". Which it may. But as noted in the linked docs, you are possibly also going to want to [override the "constructor" methods, so that your data frame type will return data frames of it's own type when using dataframe methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#override-constructor-properties).

Instead of using inheritance, [an alternative is to instead register other accessor namespaces.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#registering-custom-accessors). This is one simpler method to extend pandas, if that works for you.

Without knowing more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish, it is difficult to suggest the best way forward. But you should definitely start by reading the whole of those docs I've linked to on [Extending Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#extending-pandas)

Comment: thanks! the official docs link is very useful